# Dudas referentes a microservicios y contenedores

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Buenas tardes,
Estamos empezando a desarrollar las nuevas aplicaciones con microservicios, contendores... y estamos encontrando una serie de dudas referentes a ellos que por más que estamos buscando no conseguimos resolverlas al 100%, la cuestión es la siguiente:
Tenemos desarrollados varios microservicios y a la hora de introducirlos en el contendedor ejecutamos la siguiente sentencia por cada microservicio que creamos:

> docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name micro1 micro-service-spring-boot:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

por lo que si tenemos varios microservicios: micro1, micro2,... microN ejecutamos esta sentencia anterior tantas veces como microservicios tengamos (por lo que tenemos que cambiar el puerto).
La cosa es que si todos los microservcicios se despliegan dentro del contenedor cada uno tendrá un puerto diferente.
¿Sería posible que los microservicios se desplegarán dentro del mismo contenedor y todos tuvieran el mismo puerto y solo cambiara la ruta de acceso al mismo?

Answer (score 1):

No aconsejo realizar de esta forma el despliegue, lo mejor es desplegar los microservicios mediante Docker Swarm. Siga los siguientes pasos:

1. Cree un archivo `Dockerfile` para cada uno de los microservicios.
2. Cree un archivo `yml` para el despliegue de todos los microservicios mediante `docker-compose`.
3. Cree un script de `bash` para la construcción de las imágenes mediante `docker build`, inicio del enjambre mediante `docker init swarm` y despliegue de la solución con el archivo `yml` mediante el comando `docker stack deploy` y sus respectivas opciones.